# Showing that $f'(x)<0$ at some point of an interval.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

The function is $$f(x)= \begin{cases}2x^4 +x^4\sin(1/x),x\neq0 \\ 0,x=0 \end{cases}$$

, which has a minimum value $f(x_0 ) =0$, and $x_0 = 0$. The problem is to show, that there is no such interval $[x_0, b)$ where $b>x_0$, such that $f'(x) \geq 0 $ for all $x\in [x_0, b)$. Taking the derivative of $f$, we obtain the function $$f'(x) = (x^2)(8x-\cos(1/x) + 4x\sin(1/x).$$

Intuitively this makes sense. When $x$ becomes a very small positive number, $f'(x)$ is a very small negative number. So the function is immediately decreasing after $0$ and geometrically this can be interpreted as a negative slope and thus the result seems clear. How should I show this more rigorously?

Comment: Try to consider the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and consider large $n$. What is the sign of $f'(x_n)$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: I'll try to give you hint. Take such $x$ that $sin(1/x)=0$, while $cos (1/x)=1$. They are infinitely many such $x$-s. They should be like $\frac{1}{2\pi k}$, $k$ being positive integer. You'll get $8x^3-x^2$. The negativity should be obvious.

Comment: I don't think that is right for $f'(x).$